# How to SELECT everything FROM a table WHERE column LIKE data from other table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've done something like this to get results one by one, but now I have a list of 300 companies that I need to get data from.

```
SELECT * FROM vault
WHERE defendant_client LIKE '%Purdue Pharma%';
```

The result of this is a list of everything where the company matches.

---

But I want to select everything from vault where defendant_client (a column in vault) matches or is similar to any entry in company which is in a different table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM vault
WHERE defendant_client LIKE (SELECT company FROM OpioidCompanies);
```

It works in the sense that it runs, but no results are returned, even though I know for a fact that there are a couple of matching companies and I should be able to get a few results back.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the results I need?

Comment: First, do you mean `LIKE '%' + <some_string> + '%') or do you mean something more similar to `SOUNDEX(client) = SOUNDEX(<some_string>` or possibly `DIFFERENCE(client, <some_string>) <= <some number>)`?

Comment: Second, what do you want to happen as the company table surely has multiple rows?  Do you want to compare ***every*** client to ***every*** company?  *(As in, a `CROSS JOIN`)*?

Comment: Is this `MySQL` or `SQLite`?

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah the first one. I think

Comment: @MatBailie SQLite

Comment: @MatBailie For your second question, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM vault v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OpioidCompanies oc
              WHERE v.defendant_client LIKE '%' || oc.company || '%'
             );
```

This has two advantages over using `JOIN`:

1. If a "vault" matches more than one company, there are no duplicates.
2. The matching stops at the first match, which can be a gain for performance.

Answer (score 2):

After your most recent edit, you may want to try...

```
SELECT
    vault.*
FROM
    vault
INNER JOIN
    OpioidCompanies
        ON vault.defendant_client LIKE '%' || OpioidCompanies.company || '%'
```

If a simple `%<blah>%` isn't what you want, consider researching `SOUNDEX()` and related functions.

Comment: Updated for SQLite

Comment: Does JOIN combine the table of one with the column of the other table? Like in your example? Because one table has 300 entries and the other has 100,000

Comment: Never mind, your answer got me to what I needed, just edited it a little

Comment: That's a long conversation, `JOIN` is a fundamental operation used in `SQL`, I recommend finding a good `SQL` course online, sorry.